# A monic polynomial with integer coefficients such that both $a$ and $3a$ are roots for some complex number $a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $f(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$  be a monic polynomial such that $f(a)=f(3a)=0$ for some $a\in \mathbb C$. 
>   Then, is it true that $3|f(0)$ ?

If $g(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ , then $3^n g(x/3)$ is the minimal polynomial of $3a$, where $n=\deg g(x)$. So $f(x)=3^n g(x/3) h(x)$ for some $h(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$. Now if we knew $h(0)\in \mathbb Z$ we would be done, but I'm not sure if that is true. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is a monic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and suppose $K$ is its splitting field. Then its roots are algebraic integers in the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$, so $a$ and $3a$ are in $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Now by Vieta's formulas, the constant term of $f$ is $\pm$ the product of all roots of $f$, including $a$ and $3a$. Therefore the constant term $f(0)$ is an integer (in $\mathbb{Z}$) divisible by $3$ (in $\mathcal{O}_K$).

We write this as $f(0) = 3\alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$.

Taking field norms we find $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(f(0)) = N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(3)N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)$, so $f(0)^n = 3^n N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)$ (where $n$ is the degree of $K/\mathbb{Q}$).

Since $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)$ is an integer, this shows that $3$ divides $f(0)$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

Alternative proof:

Starting from $f(0) = 3\alpha$ where $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$, we conclude that $\frac{f(0)}{3} \in \mathcal{O}_K \cap \mathbb{Q}$. However, $\mathbb{Z}$ is integrally closed so $\mathcal{O}_K \cap \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Z}$ and we are done.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not true. Take $f(x) = (3x-1)(x-1)$ and $a= {1\over 3}$.

---

**Edit:** This answer was given before @uno edit. And then, even the answer is perfectly correct, due to unedit question, he/she down voted my answer.

Comment: Hm, I forgot that complex numbers do not always need to have an imaginary part.

Comment: Yes, every real number is also a complex. @SohamKonar

Comment: Would it be true if I assumed $f(x)$ is monic ?

Comment: Why did you down vote my answer?